Error message when trying to export linked objects from a WFS pointlayer
I am new to QGIS and therefore not that experienced with GIS programs. Currently, I am trying to export a few objects from a big WFS pointlayer to multiple smaller layers. Some of these objects are "linked", as there are two points referenced under the same entry in the attribute table. This can be seen in the added picture, where it states "Objects in total: 467, selected objects: 2" When trying to export the selected objets to a new layer I get the error message "(OGR-Error: Can only insert a Point in a esriGeometryPoint layer)". Is anyone familiar on how export these objects while keeping the information stored in the attribute table?

Looks like your target layer is not a point layer

Did you try putting the WFS layer in editing mode and then selecting the features you want and copying them to another shapefile, because when I do this, usually all the data from the attribute table comes

Thanks for the idea, but that doesnt seem to work. I can´t go into editing mode on the WFS layer. I tried duplicating the data to a temporary layer that keeps the attribute table (that I btw can´t make permanent, as the data can´t be saved), go into editing mode and copy the object to a new layer. However that doesn´t work as well, because only the location of the object will be copied to the new layer and everthing in the attribute table gets erased.

I work with WFS and I always need to log in to access the layers. I hope you find a solution, it could be either a geometry problem or perhaps a version issue. Good luck!
